# Cannot add pydoc on PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, pydoc

I cannot configure pydoc3.2 on pycharm 2.0.2. Any instructions will help me lot. Thanks.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to configure?

Comment: @yole I want to add the pydoc. That's it.

Comment: add to pydoc on the pycharm project so that when I press Ctrl+Space I get the details of methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Documentation is available on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> (default Windows Keymap or `View` | `Quick Documentation`).

If you want it to appear automatically on explicit code completion, turn on `Settings` | `Editor` | `Code Completion` | **Autopopup documentation in**...